# How to disable java icon on dock in MacOS but still display GUI?

Tags: java, macos, user-interface

I have a program that uses a GUI with the .jar file and resources packaged into a .app file with a custom icon for the .app and I wanted to know if it was possible to hide the java icon while still displaying the GUI from my .jar. Right now when I execute the .app it shows 2 icons, the icon for the application and for the .jar itself when I only want the application icon to show in the dock. I tried using -Djava.awt.UIElement=true and headless arguments but those prevent my GUI from showing.

EDIT: Or if it's possible to change the icon and label of the java icon itself to the icon I want that would work too